# How to use a converter in an jsview if statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jsrender, jsviews

So, i'm simply trying to convert an int to a bool inside of an "if" statement. I'm unsure on how to achieve this. My code that I was playing with is below.

[JsFiddle code here](http://jsfiddle.net/6t6Cn/)

The HTML:

```
<div id="main-div"></div>

<script id="testTmpl" type="text/x-jsrender">
    <input data-link="{:test:}" />
    <div data-link="{intToBool:test:}"></div>

    // testing different methods, none seem to work
    {^{if intToBool:test }}
        Woot! 1
    {{/if}}
    {^{if intToBool(test) }}
        Woot! 2
    {{/if}}
    {^{if ~root.intToBool(test) }}
        Woot! 3
    {{/if}}
</script>
```

The JavaScript:

```
 $.views.converters({
    intToBool: function(val) {
      if (val === 0 || val === false || val === '0' || val === 'false') {
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }
  });

  function App(data) {
    self = this;

    self.test = 0;
  };

  var app = new App();

  var testTmpl = $.templates("#testTmpl");
  testTmpl.link("#main-div", app);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Registering converters is only for use with the `{{: ...}}` tag (http://www.jsviews.com/#assigntag) in it's various forms `{{cvt:expression}}` `{^{cvt:expression}}` `<div data-link="{cvt:expression}">` or `<input data-link="{cvt:expression:cvtBack}" />`. See http://www.jsviews.com/#converters.

For other scenarios you need to use either a method `{^{if someMethodOnMyModel(test)}}` or a helper (http://www.jsviews.com/#helpers): `{^{if ~someHelper(test)}}`.

See also http://www.jsviews.com/#samples/jsr/paths for examples of helper paths - `~some.expression...` - to either helper function or helper objects. Note that `~root` is a built-in helper path to the top-level data object that you passed in to `render()` or `link()`.

***Edit:*** In fact there *is* a little-known feature in JsRender and JsViews which *does* let you associate registered converters with other tags. You can write

```
{^{if test convert="intToBool" }}
    Woot!
{{/if}}
```

But generally it may be simpler/better to use `~intToBool(test)` - which is more familiar, and perhaps easier to understand when reading the template.

Also BTW `{{if test}}` tests on 'truthy' so `test` does not need to be of type boolean. OTOH if you want to make "false", or "0" be falsey, then you will indeed need a helper/converter.

Comment: Okay, perfect, is '~' = '~root.' ?

Comment: Cleaned up the code one more time. http://jsfiddle.net/6t6Cn/2/ RTFM helps sometimes! Thanks Boris!

Comment: I wanted to use a converter inside for the loop. I was trying the syntax `{^{ for start=1 end=(cnvt:propname)+1 }} //logic {{/for}}`. But that did not work for me.